# Why aren't my Google maps overlays not drawn on first update?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I was following the [Google-maps overlay example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) and have modified it to fit my needs. This is my new `draw` prototype for `USGSOverlay`:

```
USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function()
{
    //need to use projection to get image position from latLng to Px
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var mapPos = new google.maps.LatLng(this.y_, this.x_);
    var posInPx = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(mapPos);

    //calculate the size in current zoom
    //imageScaleFactor is a global variable placed on top in document
    var dx = Math.abs(this.img_.naturalWidth * Math.pow(2, map.getZoom()) * imageScaleFactor);
    var dy = (dx / this.img_.naturalWidth) * this.img_.naturalHeight;

    // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
    //places the image so that the given input (x_, y_) is in the center
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = posInPx.x - dx / 2 + 'px';
    div.style.top = posInPx.y - dy / 2 + 'px';
    div.style.width = dx + 'px';
    div.style.height = dy + 'px';
};
```

When I load the page for the first time my overlays would not appear until I translated the map for a long enough distance or zoomed in/out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I the operations `this.img_.naturalWidth` and `this.img_.naturalHeight` was taking too long and didn't give a value in time for the map to be initiated where I assume it runs the draw function for each overlay once.

My solution was to add a listener for the image in the `onAdd` prototype for `USGSOverlay`:

```
var thisOverlay = this;
//draw country when image is finished loading
this.img_.onload = function(e){
    thisOverlay.draw();
}
```

This will call the draw function of the overlay once it's image is loaded.

The `thisOverlay` variable is needed because the object itself cannot be accessed from the `onload` function as far as I can tell.